# Basic WCF - how will the consumption of a WCF service translate to a 'real-life' deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service

I have created a WCF service.

I am now following tutorials on how to consume this service, and the way I've been instructed to do this is to...

**"..note the http address and port that Visual Studio is using to run you WCF webservice. It may look like this ([LOCAL HOST ADDRESS]). You will need this url from within the Windows Form to add a reference to the WCF service.."**

http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/create-and-consume-a-wcf-windows-communication-foundation-service.aspx

Now, that's fine. But if I'm literally going to copy and paste this url into my application it will no longer be relevant to a live environment will it?

Is this really the best way to point to a WCF service in a solution?

Comment: Once the wcf is added by reference it creates nodes in web.config and when going live you can change the web.config to point to live

Comment: @Sam - thanks very much mate. Must this service be developed in a separate instance of VS? I can't seem to add the web reference when I stop debugging (I'm assuming it's because my service is no longer hosted). I'm struggling to see how this is beneficial at all over asmx services in this context, getting wound up with the hoops I'm having to jump through.

Comment: When you open a service, using ServiceHost, the process must run and the service must be after .Open()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see that in your app.config file the url is saved. If you deploy your service to a live server you will only need to change the config to look at the new url.

Hope I understood your question.